# Connection to Cosmos DB via Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-cosmosdb, databricks

I tried to connect to Cosmos DB via Databricks. I use the connector from Maven (com.azure.cosmos.spark:azure-cosmos-spark_3-1_2-12:4.14.0). Here is the setup:

[image]

```
cosmosEndpoint = "https://myendpoint.documents.azure.com:443/"
cosmosMasterKey = dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "mykv", key = "my_key")
cosmosDatabaseName = "mydb"

cfg_oro = {
  "spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint" : cosmosEndpoint,
  "spark.cosmos.accountKey" : cosmosMasterKey,
  "spark.cosmos.database" : cosmosDatabaseName,
  "spark.cosmos.container" : "mycontainer",
}
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cosmosCatalog", "com.azure.cosmos.spark.CosmosCatalog")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cosmosCatalog.spark.cosmos.accountEndpoint", cosmosEndpoint)
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.cosmosCatalog.spark.cosmos.accountKey", cosmosMasterKey)
```

When I run the statement:

[image]

it keeps running and shows no result. Where is the problem coming from?

Comment: maybe you haven't enabled access from databricks VNet to cosmos db in the network/firewall settings of Cosmos?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked it in Databricks Networking and all network access are enabled and NSG rules too. FYI, it worked before but I updated the Cosmos DB Spark connector.  Possible that the problem comes from there?

Comment: maybe yes, but really you need to check driver & executor logs to see maybe there are some messages there

Comment: Thanks for you idea. Indeed, I had a look on the driver logs cluster and it seems that I have bunches of errors like the following: azure_cosmos_spark.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
 ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer... What does it mean? I forget to tell that I have a Python wheel in the cluster libraries. It might be the cause of my failure.

Comment: this error means that Cosmos closed the connection for some reason... But there could be many reasons for that, so maybe it worth support ticket

Comment: Do you mean a ticket to Github repository of the Cosmos DB connector?

Comment: No, to service itself...